# ¿Cómo obtener tablas contenidas en una página HTML?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x

Tengo una pagina HTML que obtenía con la librería newspaper. Quería obtener dos tablas que pertenecen a la página, fechas y números de curso del mercado de acciones, para crear una dataframe.

```
from newspaper import Article

url = "https://walletinvestor.com/cse-stock-forecast/luxor-b-stock-history"
article = Article(url)
article.download()
```

Puedo obtener la página gracias a `article.html` donde obtengo las fechas:

```
>>> article.html
\njQuery(\'#secondary-menu-search\').on(\'change\', function() { $(\'#secondary-menu-search-form\').submit();});\n}, 100); });\nwindow.addEventListener(\'popstate\',function(){window.location.reload();});\n;var chartJS_w0 = new Chart($(\'#w0\'),{"type":"line","data":
{"labels":["2008-10-24","2008-10-27","2008-11-03","2008-11-10","2008-11-17","2008-11-24","2008-11-11","2008-12-08","2008-12-15","2008-12-22","2008-12-29","2009-01-02","2009-01-05","2009-01-12","2008-12-17","2009-01-19","2009-01-26","2009-02-02","2009-02-09","20 ...
```

Y los precios:

```
...
"2018-11-26","2018-12-03","2018-11-26","2018-12-05"],"datasets":[{"label":"LUXOR-B","backgroundColor":Chart.helpers.color("rgb(92, 184, 92)").alpha(0.5).rgbString(),"borderColor":"rgb(92, 184, 92)","fill":false,
"data":[480,480,460,480,450,420,447.142857,320,285,320,250,250,260,270,306.578947,260,260,240,240,220,244.285714,220,90,70,85,89,126.857143,92,90,87,92,97,118,94.85,
```

Me gustaria obtener una dataframe con :

```
["2008-10-24","2008-10-27","2008-11-03","2008-11-10","2008-11-17","2008-11-24","2008-11-11","2008-12-08", ...
[480,480,460,480,450,420,447.142857, ...
```

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
# import libraries
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# specify the url
quote_page = url

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen('https://walletinvestor.com/cse-stock-forecast/luxor-b-stock-history')

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

# l = [i.get('src') for i in soup.find_all('script') if i.get('src')] 
l = [x for x in soup.find_all('script')] 
print(l[12])
```

Y puedo extraer el script que contiene las tabulas :

```
<script>jQuery(function ($) {
if (jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').data('select2')) { jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').select2('destroy'); }
jQuery.when(jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').select2(select2_e75c74dc)).done(initS2Loading('secondary-menu-search','s2options_d6851687'));
jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').on('change', function() { $('#secondary-menu-search-form').submit();});
jQuery("#currencies-table").off('pjax:complete.5d70a28f').on('pjax:complete.5d70a28f',function(){ setTimeout(function(){ if (jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').data('select2')) { jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').select2('destroy'); }
jQuery.when(jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').select2(select2_e75c74dc)).done(initS2Loading('secondary-menu-search','s2options_d6851687'));
jQuery('#secondary-menu-search').on('change', function() { $('#secondary-menu-search-form').submit();});
}, 100); });
window.addEventListener('popstate',function(){window.location.reload();});
;var chartJS_w0 = new Chart($('#w0'),{"type":"line","data":{"labels":["2008-10-24","2008-10-27","2008-11-03",
"2008-11-10","2008-11-17","2008-11-24","2008-11-11","2008-12-08",
"2008-12-15","2008-12-22","2008-12-29","2009-01-02","2009-01-05",
"2009-01-12","2008-12-17","2009-01-19","2009-01-26","2009-02-02",
"2009-02-09","2009-02-16","2009-01-29","2009-02-23","2009-03-02",
"2009-03-09","2009-03-16","2009-03-23","2009-03-07","2009-03-30",
"2009-04-06","2009-04-14","2009-04-20","2009-04-27","2009-05-04","2009-04-15","2009-05-11","2009-05-18","2009-05-25","2009-06-02","2009-06-08","2009-06-15","2009-05-27","2009-06-22","2009-06-29","2009-07-06","2009-07-13","2009-07-20","2009-07-05",
```

Pero es tonto: tengo que buscar por migo la tabla que contiene las fechas y los precios y ya no ahora una dataframe.

Comment: No se entiende lo que preguntas, mira a ver si puedes redactarlo de otra forma.

Comment: @abulafia Si, puesto al día el código para mostrar las tabulas : )

Comment: Sigo sin entender bien. ¿Puedes poner con qué código extraes de `article.html` las fechas y precios que muestras (para que pueda reproducir yo lo mismo)? Y por otro lado ¿qué es lo que quieres obtener finalmente? ¿Un dataframe pandas a partir de esas fechas y precios?

Comment: @abulafia Si, exactamente. Puesto el código para que puede pueda reproducir el lo mismo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Tanto con `newspaper.Article()` como con `urllib.open()` lo que consigues es el HTML de la página.

Usando BeautifulSoup sobre ese HTML puedes extraer como has hecho los scripts. El que contiene los datos que te interesan aparentemente es siempre el último, por lo que puedes obtenerlo de `l[-1]` en lugar de `l[12]`, lo que es seguramente más robusto por si el número de scripts que aparecen delante varía.

Ahora bien, para python ese script no es más que una cadena de texto, imposible de ejecutar o interpretar por estar en JavaScript. De modo que a partir de aquí lo que nos queda son operaciones sobre cadenas (búsquedas, splits, expresiones regulares) para tratar de extraer la parte que contiene en sí los datos. Esa parte podríamos convertirla a datos python usando el módulo `json`.

La parte difícil es dar con una forma de extraerlos que sea lo suficientemente robusta. Se me ocurre el siguiente heurístico:

- Dividir la cadena por las partes en que aparezca la palabra `"data"`, pues justo después de esa palabra es donde aparecen las listas de interés.
- No obstante tras esa división habrán trozos sin interés (separados entre sí por la palabra "data" pero que no contienen los datos que queremos). Podemos medir la longitud de cada trozo y quedarnos sólo con los que sean suficientemente largos, por ejemplo que tengan una longitud mayor de 1000 caracteres).
- Estos trozos largos contienen los datos que buscamos. Esos datos están en forma de lista delimitada por corchetes, así que podemos usar una expresión regular para capturar todo lo que aparezca entre el primer `[` y el correspondiente `]` que lo cierra.

Estas ideas se implementarán así:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

# specify the url
quote_page = url

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen('https://walletinvestor.com/cse-stock-forecast/luxor-b-stock-history')

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

js = soup.find_all("script")[-1].text
data_js = [ chunk for chunk in js.split("data") if len(chunk) >1000 ]

extract_list = re.compile(r".*?(\[.+?\]).*")
dates = extract_list.match(data_js[0]).group(1)
values = extract_list.match(data_js[1]).group(1)

dates = json.loads(dates)
values = json.loads(values)
```

Tras esto tenemos en `dates` una lista python:

```
['2008-10-24',
 '2008-10-27',
 '2008-11-03',
 ...
]
```

Y en `values` otra:

```
[480,
 480,
 460,
 480,
 450,
 420,
 447.142857,
...
]
```

Que ya son fáciles de convertir en dataframe pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime( dates ), "value": values})
df.head()
```

[image: df]

E incluso podemos pintarlo a ver si se parece al original:

```
df.plot(x="date", y="value", figsize=(15, 3))
```

[image: plot]

## Actualización

Ya que la página varía cada día y la cantidad de datos que devuelve también es variable, el heurístico de tomar los "chunks" con más de 1000 caracteres puede no funcionar.

Propongo entonces este otro. Tras partir la cadena por las apariciones de la palabra "data", intento encajar *todos y cada uno* de los trozos con la expresión regular, y me quedo con los trozos que hagan match. En los experimentos que he hecho, sólo dos encajan, y corresponden el primero a las fechas y el segundo a los datos.

Por ejemplo, lo siguiente extrae los datos del último mes:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen('https://walletinvestor.com/cse-stock-forecast/luxor-b-stock-history?chartInterval=1m')

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

js = soup.find_all("script")[-1].text

extract_list = re.compile(r".*?(\[.+?\]).*")
result = []
for chunk in js.split("data"):
  match = extract_list.match(chunk)
  if match:
    result.append(json.loads(match.group(1)))
```

Una vez tenemos en `result[0]` las fechas y en `result[1]` los valores, podemos convertirlo a dataframe. Hay que tener cuidado con lo que viene en las fechas, pues varía dependiendo de qué rango hayamos pedido al servidor web. En el ejemplo anterior en que he pedido el rango de un mes, las fechas vienen sin el año, tienen esta pinta:

```
['11-08 10:23',
 '11-08 10:23',
 '11-09 15:06',
 ...]
```

por lo que para convertirlas a objetos `datetime` correctos hay que añadirles el año (de lo contrario pandas asumirá 1900). Por ejemplo así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": result[0], "value": result[1]})
df.date = "2018-" + df.date
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Ejemplo de gráfica resultante:

```
df.plot(x="date", y="value", figsize=(15, 3))
```

[image: grafica ultimo mes]

Comment: Haa gracias pero obtengo :  `[434]` cuando hizo `print(dates)`. Intento encontrar la razón. No hay ninguno tabula en soup tampoco. Parece que hay un problema sobre la pagina ...

Comment: @ThePassenger Si, el heuristico de que haya al menos 1000 caracteres no funciona si la cantidad de datos que devuelve la página es menor. He actualizado la respuesta con otra posible forma de operar, que parece más robusta.